# How to embed fonts for Use in a Visual Basic Project?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, fonts, embedded-resource

I am trying to embed a font using the following code that I found from this site, however as I'm trying to build, I keep running into an error `'DIGITALDREAMNARROW' is not a member of 'Resources'.`. Can anyone help with where I'm supposed to do this:

Even though I have the font added to a Resources folder. Is there something I'm missing?

http://zerosandtheone.com/blogs/vb/archive/2009/11/20/vb-net-include-a-font-as-an-embedded-resource-in-your-application.aspx

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module CustomFont

'PRIVATE FONT COLLECTION TO HOLD THE DYNAMIC FONT
Private _pfc As PrivateFontCollection = Nothing


Public ReadOnly Property GetInstance(ByVal Size As Single, _
                                     ByVal style As FontStyle) As Font
    Get
        'IF THIS IS THE FIRST TIME GETTING AN INSTANCE
        'LOAD THE FONT FROM RESOURCES
        If _pfc Is Nothing Then LoadFont()

        'RETURN A NEW FONT OBJECT BASED ON THE SIZE AND STYLE PASSED IN
        Return New Font(_pfc.Families(0), Size, style)

    End Get
End Property

Private Sub LoadFont()
    Try
        'INIT THE FONT COLLECTION
        _pfc = New PrivateFontCollection

        'LOAD MEMORY POINTER FOR FONT RESOURCE
        Dim fontMemPointer As IntPtr = _
            Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem( _
            My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW.Length)

        'COPY THE DATA TO THE MEMORY LOCATION
        Marshal.Copy(My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW, _
                     0, fontMemPointer, _
                     My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW.Length)

        'LOAD THE MEMORY FONT INTO THE PRIVATE FONT COLLECTION
        _pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontMemPointer, _
                           My.Resources.DIGITALDREAMNARROW.Length)

        'FREE UNSAFE MEMORY
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontMemPointer)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'ERROR LOADING FONT. HANDLE EXCEPTION HERE
    End Try

End Sub

End Module
```

I downloaded his program source code and it works fine but when I retry it on my end, I get errors. Can anyone help?

Comment: Its says you need to set the UseCompatibleTextRendering property to true (the default is false), have you done this?!

Comment: That's not generating the error but yes, they are set to true. The specific error I'm getting is "'DIGITALDREAMNARROW' is not a member of 'Resources'."

Comment: Sounds like you need to add it to 'My Project\Resources' using 'Add Resource\Add Existing File'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a file as a resource to your project,

- Double-click **My Project** in **Solution Explorer** or your project **Properties** under the **Project** menu item.
- Select the **Resources** tab from your project **Properties**. You can add the ttf file by either choosing **Add Existing File...** from the Add Resources drop down menu, or just drag and drop from Windows Explorer. Note: if you add the ttf resource using **Add Existing File...**, you will need to change the filter to show **All Files (***.***)**.

([reference](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/netres090117.htm))